# How to read text(ASCII) files with Assimp?

Tags: c++, file-io, assimp

I can successfully read binary files of different extensions(fbx, blend, ifc and etc.) with assimp but if file is not binary assimp failed reading.

```
#include <string>

#include <assimp/cimport.h>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>

int main() {

    Assimp::Importer importer;

    std::string path = "myFile.ifc";

    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenNormals);

    if (scene == nullptr 
            || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE 
            || scene->mRootNode == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    // ProcessNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);


    return 0;
}
```

I did not find any flags in [docs](https://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/postprocess_8h.html) for solving this problem. And nowhere is it said about file types.

For example, if .fbx file in ASCII format - aiScene* is just nullptr but if .ifc file in ASCII program throw exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTMSm.png)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? C++ can read any file type. 
if ( aiScene == NULL) <code to read file normally>;

Comment: See the image at the and of the post. I passed the assimp simple .ifc file(which is not binary) and it generated this problem. Try-catch don`t catch this exception. Does Assimp can not read non-binary files?

Comment: I get it. I can't presently find any doc about supporting ASCII-based fbx in Assimp. If it can't, it's not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635736/blender-fbx-import-from-ascii-format

Answer (score 1):

The Asset-Importer-Library will detect the kind of data automatically. So when loading an IFC-File the loader will take care which kind of import much be used.

So the problem you are dealing with is not a missing ASCII-Import-Option you have forgotten.

My first guess would be that there is an issue created by your IFC-File WOuld it be possible to check it? You can create an issue-report with our [issue-tracker](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues)